# Algebra problem using quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm currently doing a physics problem and I'm stuck on a bit of algebra. Basically I have the following equation

$$\dfrac{K}{2}\Bigg{[}\dfrac{(4T_{HW}T_H - 4T_{HW}^2 -T_{H}^2 + T_H T_C)}{(2T_{HW} - T_H)^2}\Bigg{]}=0$$

I need to find $T_{HW}$. I tried replacing the variables with letters to make it easier

$$\dfrac{(4ab - 4a^2 -b^2 + bc)}{(2a - b)^2}=0$$

This looks like a quadratic formula problem. I've tried and tried to solve it but I cannot get the result that I need to prove which is $$T_{HW} = \frac{1}{2}(T_H + \sqrt{T_HT_C })$$

or

$$a =  \frac{1}{2}(b + \sqrt{bc })$$

Basically I just need a bit of help with the algebra. I know I'm missing something fairly basic but it's really bugging me.

Comment: The last term in the numerator of your substitution of letters, should be $bc$. In your scheme: $T_{HW} = a, T_H =  b, T_C= c$, and so $T_HT_C = bc$ not $ac$ as you've used.  $$\dfrac{(4ab - 4a^2 -b^2 + bc)}{(2a - b)^2}=0$$  Simply saying you replaced the values incorrectly.  I've now corrected the substitution;  you might want to rework the rest of your post, given your initial incorrect translation.

Comment: Oh, you're right! That's why I couldn't solve it.. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Glad to help, Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting for amWhy's note, your equation should be
$$\frac{4ab - 4a^2 -b^2 + bc}{(2a - b)^2}=0,$$
note that the LHS is undefined for $2a = b$, so we must assume $a \ne b/2$.

With that assumption, you have the fraction turn to zero if and only if the numerator is zero, hence you need
$$0 = 4ab - 4a^2 -b^2 + bc = -4a^2+a(4b)+(bc-b^2),$$
which by the quadratic formula yields
$$
\begin{split}
a_\pm
 &= \frac{-4b \pm \sqrt{(4b)^2-4\cdot(-4)\cdot(bc-b^2)}}{2\cdot(-4)}\\
 &= \frac{-4b \pm \sqrt{(4b)^2+16bc-16b^2}}{-8}\\
 &= \frac{b \pm \sqrt{bc}}{2}\\
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish simplifying this?